# Upgrading contract for modern compiler version

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-design

I am upgrading the old contract from 0.4.24 for new solidity compiler version 0.5.16 however it doesn't work with modern solidity compilers,

Could anyone make my contract compatible with solidity newer than 0.5.16? Thanks.

Here is the full code

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;

        return c;
    }

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
    }

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, errorMessage);
        return a % b;
    }
 }

contract Staking {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    event StartStaking(address addr, uint value, uint amount, uint time);
    event WithdrawStake(address staker, uint amount);
    event Claim(address staker, uint reward);
    event DonationDeposited(address _address, uint value);

    struct Staker
    {
        uint amount;
        uint time;
    }


    uint public LastBlock = block.number;
    uint public Timestamp = now;

    uint public TotalStakingWeight;
    uint public TotalStakingAmount;
    uint public StakingRewardPool;
    bool public CS_frozen;
    uint public staking_threshold = 0 ether;
    address public Treasury       = 0xD0eDff4E0b7e7e410F631669B040905267E9FFD1;

    uint public round_interval   = 27 days;
    uint public max_delay        = 365 * 2 days;
    uint public DateStartStaking = 1541980800;

    mapping(address => Staker) public staker;

    function freeze(bool _f) public only_treasurer
    {
        CS_frozen = _f;
    }

    function withdraw_rewards () public only_treasurer
    {
        if (CS_frozen)
        {
            StakingRewardPool = address(this).balance.sub(TotalStakingAmount);
            Treasury.transfer(StakingRewardPool);
        }
    }

    function clear_treasurer () public only_treasurer
    {
        require(block.number > 1800000 && !CS_frozen);
        Treasury = 0x00;
    }

    function() public payable
    {
        start_staking();
    }

    function new_block() public
    {
        if (block.number > LastBlock)
        {
            uint _LastBlock = LastBlock;
            LastBlock = block.number;

            StakingRewardPool = address(this).balance.sub(TotalStakingAmount + msg.value);

            if (now > Timestamp)
            {
                uint _blocks = block.number - _LastBlock;
                uint _seconds = now - Timestamp;
                if (_seconds > _blocks * 25)
                {
                    _seconds = _blocks * 25;
                }
                TotalStakingWeight += _seconds.mul(TotalStakingAmount);
                Timestamp += _seconds;
            }
        }
    }

    function start_staking() public staking_available payable
    {
        assert(msg.value >= staking_threshold);
        new_block();

        if (staker[msg.sender].amount > 0)
        {
            if (Timestamp >= staker[msg.sender].time + round_interval)
            { 
                claim(); 
            }
            TotalStakingWeight = TotalStakingWeight.sub((Timestamp.sub(staker[msg.sender].time)).mul(staker[msg.sender].amount));
        }

        TotalStakingAmount = TotalStakingAmount.add(msg.value);
        staker[msg.sender].time = Timestamp;
        staker[msg.sender].amount = staker[msg.sender].amount.add(msg.value);

        emit StartStaking(
            msg.sender,
            msg.value,
            staker[msg.sender].amount,
            staker[msg.sender].time
        );
    }

    function DEBUG_donation() public payable {
        emit DonationDeposited(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function withdraw_stake() public only_staker
    {
        new_block();
        require(Timestamp >= staker[msg.sender].time + round_interval);

        uint _amount = staker[msg.sender].amount;
        claim(); 
        TotalStakingAmount = TotalStakingAmount.sub(_amount);
        TotalStakingWeight = TotalStakingWeight.sub((Timestamp.sub(staker[msg.sender].time)).mul(staker[msg.sender].amount));

        staker[msg.sender].amount = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(_amount);
        emit WithdrawStake(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

    function claim() public only_staker
    {
        if (CS_frozen) return;

        new_block();
        uint _StakingInterval = Timestamp.sub(staker[msg.sender].time);
        if (_StakingInterval >= round_interval)
        {
            uint _CompleteRoundsInterval = (_StakingInterval / round_interval).mul(round_interval);
            uint _StakerWeight = _CompleteRoundsInterval.mul(staker[msg.sender].amount);
            uint _reward = StakingRewardPool.mul(_StakerWeight).div(TotalStakingWeight);

            StakingRewardPool = StakingRewardPool.sub(_reward);
            TotalStakingWeight = TotalStakingWeight.sub(_StakerWeight);

            staker[msg.sender].time = staker[msg.sender].time.add(_CompleteRoundsInterval);

            msg.sender.transfer(_reward);
            emit Claim(msg.sender, _reward);
        }
    }

    function stake_reward(address _addr) public constant returns (uint)
    {
        require(staker[_addr].amount > 0);
        require(!CS_frozen);

        uint _blocks = block.number - LastBlock;
        uint _seconds = now - Timestamp;
        if (_seconds > _blocks * 25)
        {
            _seconds = _blocks * 25;
        }
        uint _Timestamp = Timestamp + _seconds;
        uint _TotalStakingWeight = TotalStakingWeight + _seconds.mul(TotalStakingAmount);
        uint _StakingInterval = _Timestamp.sub(staker[_addr].time);

        uint _CompleteRoundsInterval = (_StakingInterval / round_interval).mul(round_interval);
        uint _StakerWeight = _CompleteRoundsInterval.mul(staker[_addr].amount);
        uint _StakingRewardPool = address(this).balance.sub(TotalStakingAmount);
        return _StakingRewardPool.mul(_StakerWeight).div(_TotalStakingWeight);
    }

    modifier only_staker
    {
        require(staker[msg.sender].amount > 0);
        _;
    }

    modifier staking_available
    {
        require(now >= DateStartStaking && !CS_frozen);
        _;
    }

    modifier only_treasurer
    {
        require(msg.sender == Treasury);
        _;
    }

    function report_abuse(address _addr) public only_staker
    {
        require(staker[_addr].amount > 0);
        new_block();
        require(Timestamp > staker[_addr].time.add(max_delay));

        uint _amount = staker[_addr].amount;

        TotalStakingAmount = TotalStakingAmount.sub(_amount);
        TotalStakingWeight = TotalStakingWeight.sub((Timestamp.sub(staker[_addr].time)).mul(_amount));

        staker[_addr].amount = 0;
        _addr.transfer(_amount);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problems do you have with this contract when compiling it via Solidity 0.5.16?

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov Remix doesn't work somehow :(

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how exactly it does not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your contract compatible with Solidity version 0.5.16:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;

        return c;
    }

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
    }

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, errorMessage);
        return a % b;
    }
 }

contract Staking {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    event StartStaking(address addr, uint value, uint amount, uint time);
    event WithdrawStake(address staker, uint amount);
    event Claim(address staker, uint reward);
    event DonationDeposited(address _address, uint value);

    struct Staker
    {
        uint amount;
        uint time;
    }


    uint public LastBlock = block.number;
    uint public Timestamp = now;

    uint public TotalStakingWeight;
    uint public TotalStakingAmount;
    uint public StakingRewardPool;
    bool public CS_frozen;
    uint public staking_threshold = 0 ether;
    address payable public Treasury = 0xD0eDff4E0b7e7e410F631669B040905267E9FFD1;

    uint public round_interval   = 27 days;
    uint public max_delay        = 365 * 2 days;
    uint public DateStartStaking = 1541980800;

    mapping(address => Staker) public staker;

    function freeze(bool _f) public only_treasurer
    {
        CS_frozen = _f;
    }

    function withdraw_rewards () public only_treasurer
    {
        if (CS_frozen)
        {
            StakingRewardPool = address(this).balance.sub(TotalStakingAmount);
            address(Treasury).transfer(StakingRewardPool);
        }
    }

    function clear_treasurer () public only_treasurer
    {
        require(block.number > 1800000 && !CS_frozen);
        Treasury = address(0);
    }

    function() external payable
    {
        start_staking();
    }

    function new_block() public payable
    {
        if (block.number > LastBlock)
        {
            uint _LastBlock = LastBlock;
            LastBlock = block.number;

            StakingRewardPool = address(this).balance.sub(TotalStakingAmount + msg.value);

            if (now > Timestamp)
            {
                uint _blocks = block.number - _LastBlock;
                uint _seconds = now - Timestamp;
                if (_seconds > _blocks * 25)
                {
                    _seconds = _blocks * 25;
                }
                TotalStakingWeight += _seconds.mul(TotalStakingAmount);
                Timestamp += _seconds;
            }
        }
    }

    function start_staking() public staking_available payable
    {
        assert(msg.value >= staking_threshold);
        new_block();

        if (staker[msg.sender].amount > 0)
        {
            if (Timestamp >= staker[msg.sender].time + round_interval)
            { 
                claim(); 
            }
            TotalStakingWeight = TotalStakingWeight.sub((Timestamp.sub(staker[msg.sender].time)).mul(staker[msg.sender].amount));
        }

        TotalStakingAmount = TotalStakingAmount.add(msg.value);
        staker[msg.sender].time = Timestamp;
        staker[msg.sender].amount = staker[msg.sender].amount.add(msg.value);

        emit StartStaking(
            msg.sender,
            msg.value,
            staker[msg.sender].amount,
            staker[msg.sender].time
        );
    }

    function DEBUG_donation() public payable {
        emit DonationDeposited(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function withdraw_stake() public only_staker
    {
        new_block();
        require(Timestamp >= staker[msg.sender].time + round_interval);

        uint _amount = staker[msg.sender].amount;
        claim(); 
        TotalStakingAmount = TotalStakingAmount.sub(_amount);
        TotalStakingWeight = TotalStakingWeight.sub((Timestamp.sub(staker[msg.sender].time)).mul(staker[msg.sender].amount));

        staker[msg.sender].amount = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(_amount);
        emit WithdrawStake(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

    function claim() public only_staker
    {
        if (CS_frozen) return;

        new_block();
        uint _StakingInterval = Timestamp.sub(staker[msg.sender].time);
        if (_StakingInterval >= round_interval)
        {
            uint _CompleteRoundsInterval = (_StakingInterval / round_interval).mul(round_interval);
            uint _StakerWeight = _CompleteRoundsInterval.mul(staker[msg.sender].amount);
            uint _reward = StakingRewardPool.mul(_StakerWeight).div(TotalStakingWeight);

            StakingRewardPool = StakingRewardPool.sub(_reward);
            TotalStakingWeight = TotalStakingWeight.sub(_StakerWeight);

            staker[msg.sender].time = staker[msg.sender].time.add(_CompleteRoundsInterval);

            msg.sender.transfer(_reward);
            emit Claim(msg.sender, _reward);
        }
    }

    function stake_reward(address _addr) public view returns (uint)
    {
        require(staker[_addr].amount > 0);
        require(!CS_frozen);

        uint _blocks = block.number - LastBlock;
        uint _seconds = now - Timestamp;
        if (_seconds > _blocks * 25)
        {
            _seconds = _blocks * 25;
        }
        uint _Timestamp = Timestamp + _seconds;
        uint _TotalStakingWeight = TotalStakingWeight + _seconds.mul(TotalStakingAmount);
        uint _StakingInterval = _Timestamp.sub(staker[_addr].time);

        uint _CompleteRoundsInterval = (_StakingInterval / round_interval).mul(round_interval);
        uint _StakerWeight = _CompleteRoundsInterval.mul(staker[_addr].amount);
        uint _StakingRewardPool = address(this).balance.sub(TotalStakingAmount);
        return _StakingRewardPool.mul(_StakerWeight).div(_TotalStakingWeight);
    }

    modifier only_staker
    {
        require(staker[msg.sender].amount > 0);
        _;
    }

    modifier staking_available
    {
        require(now >= DateStartStaking && !CS_frozen);
        _;
    }

    modifier only_treasurer
    {
        require(msg.sender == Treasury);
        _;
    }

    function report_abuse(address payable _addr) public only_staker
    {
        require(staker[_addr].amount > 0);
        new_block();
        require(Timestamp > staker[_addr].time.add(max_delay));

        uint _amount = staker[_addr].amount;

        TotalStakingAmount = TotalStakingAmount.sub(_amount);
        TotalStakingWeight = TotalStakingWeight.sub((Timestamp.sub(staker[_addr].time)).mul(_amount));

        staker[_addr].amount = 0;
        address(_addr).transfer(_amount);
    }
}
```

Changes were needed mostly, because of [the solidity 0.5 breaking changes](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html):

1. Fallback functions must be declared now with `external` modifier.
2. `constant` modifier is now deprecated and must be replaced with `view` or `pure` depends on the logic.
3. `.transfer()` can be used only when the address is created as `address payable`. Also stick to using it this way `address(_addr).transfer(_amount);` by wrapping `_addr` into `address()` method.
4. In your `clear_treasurer` method I resetted your variable like this: `Treasury = address(0);`.
5. Whenever `msg.value` is used the method must contain `payable` modifier.

However please double check again your smart contract and never fully trust to provided code from here.